# Show values that doesn't matching between two columns oof 2 data frames in pandas

Tags: pandas, compare, distinct-values

I would like to see the non-matching values of two columns of 2 data frames, and also if possible doing like a distinct count of those values that way won't show them repeated

I got these colums from  2 data frames:

```
df1:

ID

M1
M1
M2
M2
M3
M4
M5
M5
M6
M6

df2:

ID

M1
M1
M2
M2
M3
M3

expected result:

Output:
M4
M5
M6


Thanks!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He needs what is not in `df2`

```
out = df1.loc[~df1.ID.isin(df2.ID)].unique()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `isin` with `unique`

```
out = df1.loc[~df1.ID.isin(df2.ID)].unique()
```